# GTK C Listview update dynamicaly

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gtk, gtk3

I am having a glade with some text entry boxes and one list view. I want to change the value of the listview according the value entered in textentry.How can i accomplish this?I didnt find any good tutorial on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment1">
    <property name="upper">100</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="liststore1">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name Xaxis -->
      <column type="gint"/>
    </columns>
    <data>
      <row>
        <col id="0">0</col>
      </row>
    </data>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="hadjustment">adjustment1</property>
            <property name="vadjustment">adjustment1</property>
            <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="model">liststore1</property>
                <child internal-child="selection">
                  <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection1"/>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn1">
                    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Xaxis</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkCellRendererSpin" id="cellrendererspin1">
                        <property name="editable">True</property>
                        <property name="adjustment">adjustment1</property>
                      </object>
                      <attributes>
                        <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                      </attributes>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Value</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="invisible_char">•</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

This is the glade file.The c file used to load glade fle

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *object, gpointer user_data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "test.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (on_window_destroy), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show (window);       
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify a bit what you want, to change the value in the treeview, or add new values to it when the user activates the entry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps. This is the same code you published just tweaked a bit. Here it's defined a callback which will be called when [the entry is activated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate). The callback is **on_entry_activated**, as you can see the value of the entry is parsed into an integer and according to its value its appended or replace the first value. The important parts are:

- the store object is passed to the callback back there in the **main** function so you can change it later.
- the values in the store (**[GtkListStore](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html)**) are manipulated using **GtkTreeIter** objects

as

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_entry_activated (GtkEntry *entry, gpointer user_data)
{
  gint64 i64;
  gint i;
  GtkListStore *store = (GtkListStore*) user_data;
  GtkTreeIter iter;

  i64 = g_ascii_strtoll (gtk_entry_get_text (entry), NULL, 10);
  i = i64;

  if (i > 0)
    {
      gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first (GTK_TREE_MODEL (store), &iter);
    }
  else
    {
      gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
    }

  gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
              0, i,
              -1);

  gtk_entry_set_text (entry, "");
}

void on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *object, gpointer user_data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkListStore *liststore1;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "test.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (on_window_destroy), NULL);

    entry = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "entry1"));
    liststore1 = GTK_LIST_STORE (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "liststore1"));
    g_signal_connect (entry, "activate", G_CALLBACK (on_entry_activated), liststore1);

    gtk_widget_show (window);
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whatif i had more than one i mean more than one entry box and similar display widgets

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we could see the things you tried before posting here... Now we can't tell if your problem is glade, gobject, or one of the GTK widgets.

Anyway, you want to use `gtk_builder_get_object()` to find the widgets, then connect to either the [`activate`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate) signal of the entry or the `notify` signal for the [`text`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry--text) property of the Entry (depending on whether you want things to happen on pressing enter or while the user types). Then in the signal handler you should modify the treeview in whatever way you wanted to modify it.